# Sqlite pcl xamarin not result query width where not in

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have a query with not in (select id from table) that works fine in sql brower but running with the library does not work. Does anyone have any tips?

My query

```
return await dbConn.QueryAsync<dbo_equipePessoa>("select idEquipePessoa, nomePessoa, idEquipe from dbo_equipePessoa where idEquipe = '2' and idEquipePessoa NOT IN (select pessoa from dbo_registro_dado where fim = '')");
```

Comment: `...does not work` What does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the database, solved!